# Why is my straight edge getting distorted when I bevel it?

Tags: bevel

I have a straight edge that I want to bevel...

[image]

When I apply the bevel it crimps and gets distorted...

[image]

How can I get a straight smooth bevel all the way down?  Here is my blend file...

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ZnFrE6fxi_SlJ2SFo2UVFHakU/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like not all the adjacent faces are connected. The big face on top of the side panels are the problem (image 1). You just need to connect them to the rest. To do that, just create an edge loop on it and merge (Alt+M) the bottom vertex with the one on the top of the wheel hole (image 2). That should do it (image 3).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks I'm sure you are right since you tested it already.  I still can't wrap my head around why this would be a problem.  With time hopefully it will sink in.  Do you think I could just redefine the large face to include the vertex on top of the tire?

Comment: Redefining the face to include the vertex on top of the tire worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

You've got non *manifold elements* there (verts aren't merged properly). In side view snap the *knife* (press <kbd>K</kbd>) to the vertex as pictured below. Then press <kbd>Z</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd> to cut through the model and make the cut go straight. Drag the mouse upwards.
[image]

Next *remove doubles* (in *Edit Mode* select the whole mesh with <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Remove Doubles*).
[image]

Now the bevel works fine.
[image]

***Some tips:*** To increase the modeling speed you may delete half of the model and give it a *Mirror Modifier*.
[image]

Also you may consider changing the mesh topology to make the edge loops work properly. 
[image]

Comment: Why would you repeat my answer?

Comment: I started to write my answer before you posted yours, then had a phonecall and left it undone. After I finished talking you posted your answer. I just didn't want to waste my efforts so published mine:). +1 from me as you posted the solution first.